# Python - Regular Expression for match in CSV or XLS, and return location of match

Tags: python, csv, expression, xls

I am looking to use a regular expression to search for a string value in a csv or xls file, and then have the (row, column) location of the match(es) be returned to me. I am having trouble with both the search, and the command to return the cell location of the match. Any tips to make this easy for Python?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import re
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from pandas import *
from xlsxwriter import worksheet

def search_method(patterns, phrase):
    for pat in patterns:
        print("Searching fo pattern {}".format(pat))
        print('\n')

new_data = ''

with open(new_data) as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)

    data = list(csv.reader(csvDataFile))

    print(data[1])

test_phrase = data
test_patterns = ['S/N:{1}']
search_method(test_patterns, test_phrase)
print(type(data))
print(search_method(test_patterns, test_phrase))
```

Answer (score 0):

For RegEx you need to do re.compile and use search() to find the expression in each comma seperated value

```
pattern = re.compile('S/N:{1}']
```

Thus in your search_method you want something like:

```
def search_method(pattern, file):
    lineByColumn = {}
    for line, bit in enumerate(file):
        for column, pat in enumerate(file):
            if pattern.search(pat):
                map[line] = column
```

This will give you a "map" with the lines pointing to the columns of the csv with the matching phrase

Comment: I haven't tested it since I don't have a csv file readily available